# Time Complexity Analysis Of A Recursion

Tags: matlab, complexity-theory

The following code is calculating the determinant using recursion.

For the "for" loop with have O(n) then we call the function again with n-1 elements so we have to multiply each time we call the function?
 something like O(n)*O(n-1)*...*O(1)?

```
    function y = detm(A)
    n = length(A);
    y = 0;
    if n == 1
        y = A(1,1);
    elseif n == 2
        y = A(1,1).*A(2,2)-A(1,2).*A(2,1);
    elseif n > 2
        for i = 1:n
           temp = A(2:end,:);
           temp(:,i) = [];
           if mod(i,2) == 0
               y = y - A(1,i)*detm(temp);
           else
               y = y + A(1,i)*detm(temp);
           end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: you may mean `O(n!)`?

Comment: You are right. Furthermore, using the product property (see Wiki page on Big O notation) it will be equal to `O(n!)`